# How to use CanvasAuthorizer

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I download the latest version and successfully tested the Mvc3Web sample.
I tried to extend it to get email and friends but the CanvasAuthorizer is failing.
The code below is not working:
CanvasAuthorizer _authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer {Permissions = {"publish_stream,offline_access"};
throwing an exception complaining about appId being empty.
Any idea how to acheive this? It's pitty that the samples are missing the permissions request functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the code to use permissions as array.

```
CanvasAuthorizer _authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer {Permissions = new[] {"publish_stream", "offline_access"}};
```

Update:
Also make sure to have proper app settings in web.config for the application.
 or set it programatically (during application_beginrequest)

```
FacebookApplication.SetApplication(new DefaultFacebookApplication{ AppId = "...", AppSecret = "..." });
```

Comment: Made the changes above and now when calling _authorizer.Authorize()  I get the following error: CanvasUrl is null or empty

Comment: make sure to set the values in web.config, checkout the samples folder in the source code